# Javascript OnClick action change href

Tags: html

HI I'm new in javascript and i wanna do a Javascript on click. I have an image with 2 other image the First image will change when i click on the other 2 but the main image has a zoom button and i want the on click script to change the zoom icon's href link as well and i don't know how to do that can someone help me? THX a lot.

Here is my code after some research but it doesn't work.

```html
<article class="javascript html">
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function change(menuId, image, newImage, newUrl)
{
    var img = document.getElementById(image);
    img.src = newImage;
    document.getElementById('d3').href = newUrl;
} 
</script>
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div id="main_img">
             <img id="img" src="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" alt=""/>
            <div class="caption">
                <span class="ico-block">
                    <a class="ico-zoom" href="assets/example/latest/S8621A.png" id="d3"><span></span></a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        <div style="text-align:center">
<div id="thumb_img">
    <img src='assets/img/fekete.png' onclick='changeImage("assets/example/latest/S8621A.png")' >
    <img src='assets/img/barna.png' onclick='changeImage("assets/example/latest/S8621B.png")' onclick='document.getElementById'("d3").href = '(assets/example/latest/S8621B.png)'>
</div></div>
    </article>
```

Comment: You are not triggering the `change` functions onclick. You are triggering `changeImage`...

Comment: How can i Trigger that then?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call the function like this:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" onclick="change()">
```

The parameter, the attribute `onclick` expects, is named `change()` and this will be the function it will call:

```
function change() {
    // define here what the function will do...
}
```

As your function needed some parameters, you can do the following:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" onclick="change(param1, param2, param3, param4)">
```

The function `change()` expects now 4 parameters

```
function change(param1, param2, param3, param4) {
    // ...
}
```

That's how you should begin

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function is defined as `changeImage` but in your `onclick` handler you are calling a function called `change` which doesn't exist.

Solution: `onclick="change(`...

2. You don't need the second `onclick` handler in the image tag. The function `change` contains the code to swap `d3` href.
3. The function `change` expects 4 arguments

`change(menuId, image, newImage, newUrl)`

You are only passing one in - an image URL, and because this is being passed in as the first argument, the function `change` sees it as the argument `menuId`, and so `image`, `newImage`, and `newUrl` are all undefined.